# Why Birthday/Event day is called birthday/Even tday but not birth/Event dayMonth

Tags: word-usage

My birthday is 26 Jun 1992 assume I Celebrate birthday on 26 of June every year.
So if it's birthDAY,then I, can celebrate Every 26(Not possible if I was born on 30th though).
My question is why they skip the Month even though it is taken into account..
Not only for birthday but also for other special days like Independence day.
Is it just for simple usage or is there any other way to express it.
I mean if day is preceded by an Event it most probably a day+month then why they skip the month.I can use anniversary to overcome this problem.But is there any reason for the stated question?

Comment: Guessing here...it's because the ***duration*** of the celebration, whether it's a birthday or holiday, is one day (24 hours).  For events like Breast Cancer Awareness - the duration of the event is a month so it's called "Breast Cancer Awareness Month".

Comment: *day* refers to when you were born (as in your day of birth), not how often you celebrate it.  *birth month* and *birth year* have similar respective meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of *[birthday](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/birthday)* establishes an annual cycle:

> noun
>
> 1 The anniversary of the day on which a person was born, typically
>   treated as an occasion for celebration and the giving of gifts:
>
> *ODO*

Even though an annual cycle is customary, it is not required. For the first year of my first-born daughter's life, my wife and I celebrated her birthday each month on the third, because she was born on the third. After the first year, we decided that the customary annual celebration was sufficient.

It really wouldn't be fair to people born on the 31st of a month, if we celebrated monthly, because they would miss five celebrations every year. ;-)

The word *[day](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/day?q=-day)* does a lot of semantic work:

> noun
>
> 1.0 Each of the twenty-four-hour periods, reckoned from one midnight to the next, into which a week, month, or year is divided, and
>   corresponding to a rotation of the earth on its axis:
>
> 1.1 The part of a day when it is light; the time between sunrise and sunset:
>
> 1.2 The part of a day spent working:
>
> 1.3 Astronomy A single rotation of a planet in relation to its primary.
>
> 1.4 Astronomy The period on a planet when its primary star is above the horizon.
>
> 1.5 [MASS NOUN] archaic or literary Daylight:
>
> 2.0 (also days) A particular period of the past; an era:
>
> 2.1 (the day) The present time:
>
> 2.2 (usually with modifier days) A particular period in a person’s life or career:
>
> 2.3 (one's day) The most active or successful period of a person’s life or career:
>
> 2.4 (one's days) The remaining period of someone’s life:

Used as in ***birthday*** or ***holiday***, it carries an annual connotation.

Answer (score 1):

The convention in most cultures I'm familiar with is that the Year is the major repeating element in the calendar. That is, there's a stronger connection between a specific Day of Year in different years (say, April 27th 2015 and April 27th 2014) than there is between a specific Day of Month in different months.

I think that for cultures using [Solar calendars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_calendar), like Western Europe, a month is a relatively arbitrary division, whereas the solar cycles (a day and a year) correspond to noticeable changes in the world - January 5th would be winter every year (in the northern hemisphere). What would the 5th of every month have in common with the 5th of any other month?

You can find some things attached to monthly recurrences - events happening "on the 6th of every month" and so on, but even those are usually aligned to a weekly calendar ("second Monday of every month") rather than a monthly calendar. Months are simply not that *useful*, in the modern western world.

Answer (score 0):

My original comment to the OP:

> It's because the duration of the celebration, whether it's a birthday
>   or holiday, is one day (24 hours). For events like Breast Cancer
>   Awareness - the duration of the event is a month so it's called
>   "Breast Cancer Awareness Month".

**Expanding on my comment:**

From Etymonline.com, the etymology of "[birthday](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=birthday)":

> late 14c., from Old English byrddæg, "anniversary celebration of someone's birth" (at first usually a king or saint)

It's the *celebration* of a particular anniversary that defines the "day" in birthday or Independence Day.